# Is there a linux terminal with emacs keybindings?

Tags: term

I sometimes need to work in a terminal. E.g compile gtk.

I found that the native emacs shell doesn't quite do what a native terminal does. And anyway I'd like to keep them two separate.

Now, is there a terminal that has a similar feel as emacs? like C-x-3 to slip windows etc..

(e.g for firefox there are firemacs bindings, for eclipse there is emacs+ plugin) etc...

**[Edit]**
If you down vote, please leave a comment explaining why so I can improve question.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as Jordan did in his deleted answer. The likes of [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) make this possible. You can create your custom bindings in tmux just as in emacs.

Comment: You can create custom bindings in a terminal, by putting in your `.bashrc`, lines like: `bind -x '"\C-xt":tmux'` to bind the `tmux` command to the `C-x-t` shortcut. And yeah, `tmux`, is also a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or almost any other terminal multiplexer. It won't immediately have Emacs-like bindings, but like emacs, you can customize it to suit your needs. See this question: [how-to-force-emacs-style-status-keys-in-tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240683/how-to-force-emacs-style-status-keys-in-tmux)

Comment: Most of my emacs collegues seem to be using Tmux. I guess I should give it  a shot. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Is perhaps `M-x shell` what you are looking for?

This shell mode is different from Emacs' native shell *eshell*. Since it's running from within Emacs one can do `C-x 3` and all the usual juggling.
You can run several instances by using a prefix argument (`C-u M-x shell`).

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to do the job. 1) For example there is no syntax highlighting on a 'git status', 2) It's non-trivially slower than something like Terminator. e.g doing 'find . | grep Leo' takes ~1 second in Terminator, and almost 15 seconds in emacs shell. 3) As you mentioned, you can only have one of it, I often need like 5.  That said, it's nice for little things, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: OK. Emacs shell isn't a good alternative then. It doesn't fulfil your requirements.